# Processing array of object using promise in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I have array of objects like this:

    `$scope.userList = [{"Name" : "Sumit", "Surname" : "Ranjan"}, {"Name" : "Claudio", "Surname" : "Gomes"}, {"Name" : "Sumit", "Mwanda" : "Mwanda"}];`

I using a REST API to create user in backend. I have created a service factor to do this.

I want to upload user one by one. I am showing a loading icon using $ionicLoading before starting the process and want to close this only after all item of the array has been processed.

following is my code:

//To show loading icon

```
var showLoading = function() {
$ionicLoading.show({
content: 'Loading',
animation: 'fade-in',
showBackdrop: true,
maxWidth: 200,
showDelay: 0
});
}
```

Then running loop to process each item

```
for(var i=0; i< Object.keys($scope.userList).length; i++){
var promise = CreateNewUser.create( {
$scope.userList[i];
}
}).$promise;
promise.then(function(_response) {
//to-do some local stuff here
})
}
```

My problem is that, loading icon gets unload without processing all item in loop.
How can I close the loading icon only all items in the array has been processed in loop.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Sumit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller :

```
$scope.userList = [{"Name" : "Sumit", "Surname" : "Ranjan"}, {"Name" : "Claudio", "Surname" : "Gomes"}, {"Name" : "Sumit", "Mwanda" : "Mwanda"}];
$scope.showLoading = function() {
  $ionicLoading.show({
    content: 'Loading',
    animation: 'fade-in',
    showBackdrop: true,
    maxWidth: 200,
    showDelay: 0
  });
}

$scope.hide = function(){
  $ionicLoading.hide();
};
$scope.createNewUsers = function () {
 $scope.showLoading();
 var promiseArray = [];

 for(var i=0; i< Object.keys($scope.userList).length; i++){
   var aPromise = CreateNewUser.create( {
       $scope.userList[i];
   }
    promiseArray.push(aPromise);
 }

 $q.all(promiseArray).then(function(){
    $scope.hide();
 })
}

//call the method wherever you want..!
$scope.createNewUsers();
```

if this doesn't work..!
then TRY passing the complete `$scope.userList` to service and make same implementation in `CreateNewUser.create();`

Also Check [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Hope this is a help..!